# GoDaddy shared hosting two differnt sites running different php versions

Tags: php, ini, shared-hosting

I am running a GoDaddy shared hosting package. I need one site to run php 7.4.11 and the other to run php 5.6

The server default php version is 7.4.11

I have already tried creating a `.user.ini` file within the site folder and inputting the reference url path `session.save_path = "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php56"` with no luck.
I have also tried to dump the php56.php file content inside of .user.ini but that also didnt seem to work.

I have killed the php process each test and im using phpinfo.php to check the results.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I just solved a similar problem on my VPS with Godaddy.  In my case, the GoDaddy cPanel said my PHP version was 8.0, but my wordpress installation was complaining that I was running php 5.6. GoDaddy support told me it was not supported to have multiple versions on my VPS, but he referenced that I might be able to do it using .htaccess directives - but it was up to me.  I opened .htaccess in the root folder of my site (public_html) and noticed this line:

AddHandler application/x-httpd-alt-php56___lsphp .php

I changed the '56' to '71' and re-ran my wordpress site, it now complained that the PHP version was 7.1 (progress!).  I kept increasing 71-72-73 until it stopped complaining. with '74', the wordpress site stopped complaining about PHP version, but still ran, suggesting php 7.4 was the highest version that particular wordpress release could handle. (I tried '80' but WP site crashed, suggesting my old wordpress was not compatible with php 8.0).

Next, rather than add this directive to the 'root' (public_html) folder, I put it in the specific folder for the WP site, and it worked.  So now, my overall site is able to run php 8 (the VPS site version) but my WP installation is running 7.4, the highest supported by my WP software.

I didn't put these directives in .htaccess in the first place so I suspect it was put there by goDaddy, but their support were oblivious.

Answer (score 0):

I would reach out to GoDaddy and have them assist - they might have a preferred method.

However, if you have cPanel access you can use MultiPHP Manager and specify what PHP version to use per site. That is if GoDaddy has this setup in the first place.

Comment: MultiPHP is not an option with shared hosting on GoDaddy, according to their phone tech support it is not possible to set different sites to run different versions of PHP on a shared hosting platform.

I used to have hosting with Startlogic and I know through their shared hosting you just set each site a different `.ini` file.